# How do I find a the first instance of an event in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet of data from my CC processor.  I want to be able to track new customer acquisition against ad spend on various platforms by month.  When I download the data from my CC processor I have a columns for, amongst other items, CustomerName & OrderDate.  I need to create a pivot table, or other table, showing the month of only the first instance each CustomerName created their first order.

I have a tab where the timestamps are converted to display only the month of the purchase as well as the year in separate column using the =Eomonth formula.  From there I get lost as to the next steps to parse out only the first instance of a particular customer purchase.

I've included mock customer names that mirror the format

Help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Customer Purchase Dates]

[image: Customer Purchase Dates Formula]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C, B2:B, 1, MONTH(A2:A&1), 1), 9^9, 2, 3, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I copied that formula in and spot checked the results.  That formula seems to be working for some of the customer names, but not all, and there doesn't seem to be a clear pattern as to those that do and don't work.  With some results the formula returns the earliest instance.  With others it's grabbing the last instance, or an arbitrary instance in the middle.  I've ensured no whitespace at the end of each name to eliminate the possibility the names are being read as unique values.

Comment: @Nick can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here is a copy of the sheet with all names replaced.  As an example If you compare '!Nethaniel Dilhinger!" on the "1st Instance" tab to that person's first purchase on either the "Sheet1" or "Month Converter" tab you can see the discrepancy.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7nG65hm2KCAddAt0uv1C0GLzvQBHljXjQO_1qp-yaw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nick if you want to use you Month Converter sheet as source for the formula use: `=SORTN(SORT('Month Converter'!A2:C,'Month Converter'!B2:B,1,MONTH(TO_TEXT('Month Converter'!A2:A)&1),1),9^9,2,3,1)`

Comment: @Nick but you can do it directly too: `=SORTN(SORT({TEXT(Sheet1!B2:B, {"mmmm", "yyyy"}), Sheet1!D2:D}, Sheet1!B2:B, 1), 9^9, 2, 3, 1)`